# Bash Script for Load Data Infile MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, eof, load-data-infile

So i'm trying to create a script that I can run that will do a batch import of csv files into a table.

I'm having trouble getting the script to work.

Here is the script i'm running:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.csv
do
"/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -e use test -e LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ("$f") INTO TABLE temp_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (DATE, TIME, SITE_NAME, SITE_IP, TOTAL_TALKTIME, EDGE_UL_BYTES, EDGE_DL_BYTES);"
done
```

When I run the script I receive the following error message:

```
./script.sh: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./script.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The load data local infile command works fine directly in mysql.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you want to use literal double quotes in double quoted strings, escape them with `\"`. Since mysql doesn't care about line feeds, you can also break the line to make it more readable:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.csv
do
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -e "use test" -e "
      LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$f'
      INTO TABLE temp_table 
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
      OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
      IGNORE 1 LINES 
      (DATE, TIME, SITE_NAME, SITE_IP, TOTAL_TALKTIME, 
           EDGE_UL_BYTES, EDGE_DL_BYTES);"
done
```

Comment: You don't really need to escape newlines in this case.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ("csv_name.csv") INTO TABLE temp_table' at line 1

Comment: @XFerrariX remove both \" in INFILE (\"$f\") .. or replace them with '

Comment: Thanks so much @that other guy. Your script aboves works great.

Comment: I inherited a script that was using "mysql < $infile" format, and this was the direction it needed to go to work thanks @thatotherguy

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -u<username> -p<password> -h<hostname> <db_name> --local_infile=1 -e "use <db_name>" -e"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '<path/file_name>' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE <table_name>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'"
```